# Is it okay to reference a third table in a many-to-many join table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

I am designing a relational database for projects and tasks.  I want projects and tasks to be able to be classified or grouped by category.

If a project is shared by two or more users, I want each user to be able to categorize the project separately.  Additionally, I want users to be able to share entire categories with each other, including all projects and tasks within that category.  Therefore, here is the schema that I have come up with in terms of a basic ERD:

[image]

Here are my main models in Rails:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :user_categories
  has_many :projects, :through => :user_projects
  has_many :categories, :through => :user_categories
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, :through => :user_projects
  has_many :tasks, :as => :taskable
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taskable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_categories
  has_many :users, :through => :user_categories
  has_many :tasks, :as => :taskable
end
```

Is it okay to include a category_id foreign key in the User_Project join (junction) table like this?  Also, do you see any problems with this schema in general?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the design seems fine just make sure you add indexes on foreign keys too

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked if we saw any problems with the schema in general, ...,

The relationship between tasks and projects is not clear.  If it's the taskable_id, that's a strange column name.  Why not go with project_id?

There is also a lack of flexibility.  You said that you want to allow users to share categories and your schema seems to support that.  What I don't see is anything that allows two users to work on different tasks on the same project.  That seems to be something that could happen in real life.

I'm puzzled about the User_Category table.  Do categories apply to both users and projects?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The taskable name is based on a Rails convention for Polymorphic models.  I still need to add a relation for tasks and users.  A user can have multiple project/task categories and a project/task category can be shared by multiple users, so the User_Category table is just a standard join table to support that many-to-many relationship.